# Newly installed 16.04 LTS give random crashes

Tags: 16.04

On a freshly installed 16.04 i386 I get apport crashes when:

- adjusting the audiolevel when watching a Youtube video (every time)
- logging ind (now and then)

Is there a tool to check that all installed files are properly installed (with correct checksum) and no files are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dpkg -V
```

It can even be run as a normal user for most files (i.e. files with user read permission).